# How to get a full size of directory without listing the files/dir within?

Tags: files, directory, du

I am able to get a size of a directory at the end of the `du -h directoryname`. **But is there a way to get the size without it listing the files/directories within?**

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
du -h directoryname | tail -n1
```

**How to keep an index of directory sizes? Is there an Ubuntu application/software for that?**

Answer (score 17):

The `-s` option for `du` will give you an output which is just the summary, so swap your command to:

```
du -sh /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
du -d 0 -h directoryname
```

From `man du`:

> **-d, --max-depth=N**
>   print the total for a directory (or file, with --all) only if it is   N   or  fewer  levels  below  the  command  line  argument;

If you want a GUI application to do that, you can use Disk Usage Analyzer (or `baobab`), to check:

[image]

Or use the 'Properties' feature (in most file managers):

> [image]

The last one I think caches a bit unless a noticeable change occurs (in Nemo anyway).

Comment: I'm curious to know what theme are you using?

Comment: @RahilWazir [Arc](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme)-Darker on Gnome 3.14 :)

Comment: The `-S` switch is equivalent to `-d 0`, (and shorter); for details see `info du | sed -n "/‘-\(S’$\|d \)/,/^$/p"`.